# Pass Textbox Data To A Javascript Array Using Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, textbox

what is the simplest way to type in a textbox, ng-click a button and send that text from the textbox to an array? I've put question marks to show where I know code goes, but I'm not sure what. Here's my code:

My HTML Looks like this:

```
<input class="textBox" style="width: 320px; color:black; margin-bottom:20px" type="text"/>

<input class="button" style="width:100px" ng-click="addWorkflow(?,?); toggleShow('addWorkflow')" type="submit" value="Add">
```

This is the JS array I want the typed text to go to, specifically the "Name" and "Description" objects.

```
 $scope.addWorkflow = function(?, ?) {
  var workflow = {
       Id: 0,
       Name: ?,
       Description: ?,
       Lens: "",
       Focus: "",
       Aperture: ""
   } 

   $scope.workflows.push(workflow);

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try this:

```
$scope.addWorkflow = function(newWorkflow) {
var workflow = {
   Id: 0,
   Name:"This is where I want the text from the text box to appear.",
   Description: "",
   Lens: "",
   Focus: "",
   Aperture: ""
} 
var textBox=document.getElementsByClassName("textBox")[0];
workflow.Name=textBox.value;

$scope.workflows.push(workflow);

};
```

But if you give your input an `id="textBox"` it would be better because the class attribute could be given to many elements and an id is specific for only one element:

```
<input class="textBox" id="textBox" style="width: 320px; color:black; margin-bottom:20px" type="text"/>
```

And then use:

```
var textBox=document.getElementById("textBox");
workflow.Name=textBox.value;
```

**EDIT:**

This is how you whould do to get the inputted values:

```
<input class="textBox" id="name" style="width: 320px; color:black; margin-bottom:20px" type="text"/>
<input class="textBox" id="description" style="width: 320px; color:black; margin-bottom:20px" type="text"/>
<input class="button" style="width:100px" ng-click="addWorkflow(); toggleShow('addWorkflow')" type="submit" value="Add">
```

Then your function will be:

```
$scope.addWorkflow = function(newWorkflow) {
var workflow = {
   Id: 0,
   Name:"This is where I want the text from the text box to appear.",
   Description: "",
   Lens: "",
   Focus: "",
   Aperture: ""
} 
var nameText=document.getElementById("name");
workflow.Name=nameText.value;
var descText=document.getElementById("description");
workflow.Description=descText.value;

$scope.workflows.push(workflow);

};
```

Comment: Ok that helped, but I'm looking for a simpler way to do this. I've added the question marks to places I know code goes but I can't figure out what.

Comment: @Bradston07 take a look at my EDIT I think this is what you're searching